# What does the abbreviation NB mean?

Tags: information-theory, jensen-inequality

In Appendix B "Jensen's inequality" of "Information theory and coding" by McEliece, the abbreviation (NB) is repeatedly used in the statements of theorems B.1 and B.2. However I cannot locate where in the book the abbreviation is explained.

> Theorem B.1 *Let I be a discrete set of integers, and let $p_i,i\in I$, be a set of positive (NB) real numbers such that $\sum_{i\in I}p_i=1$. If $q_i$ is any other set of nonnegative (NB) real numbers....*

Similarly for theorem B.2.

There is nothing in the index labelled "NB", and even downloading a scan and searching for NB got me nowhere. I also looked in Feller's book on probability which McEliece uses as a reference, but could not find it.

The only thing that NB usually stands for seems to be "Nota Bene" or "note well", so is this just an alert to the reader?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: I would guess it does mean "nota bene" in this case, and is alerting you to the change from positive to non-negative.

Comment: Except that elsewhere nota bene is written N.B., not NB.

Comment: Possibly "non-binary"? I do not have a copy of the book nor am I an expert in the field so I don't know if that term would be relevant. But a Google search for the author and "NB" turns up [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337229244_Using_Non-Binary_LDPC_and_MDPC_Codes_in_the_McEliece_Cryptosystem) though I don't see an actual usage of the abbreviation in it.